# From a subset of foreign keys, get a list of items that contain that subset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

- pages_interests

  - page_id INT NOT NULL
  - interest_id INT NOT NULL
- items_interests

  - item_id INT NOT NULL
  - interest_id INT NOT NULL

pages_interest:

| page_id | interest_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 89 |

items_interest:

| item_id | interest_id |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 7 |
| 10 | 20 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 55 |

I'm trying to figure out how to get SQL to join on multiple rows. Because the page expected items to have an interest of 1 and 7, get items that have both those interests, but don't discard when an item has other interests too.
The expected output would be:

| page_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 12 |

Does anyone have any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work. I added a couple of more pages for more realistic test:

```sql
;with pages as (
    select *
    from (
        VALUES  (1, 1)
        ,   (1, 7)
        ,   (2, 1)
        ,   (3, 1)
        ,   (3, 7)
        ,   (3, 89)
        ,   (4, 20)
        ,   (5, 55)
        ,   (5, 1)
        ,   (6, 1)
        ,   (6, 13)
    ) t (page_id,interest_id)
)
, items as (
    select  *
        from (
        VALUES  (10, 1)
        ,   (10, 7)
        ,   (10, 20)
        ,   (12, 1)
        ,   (12, 55)
    ) t (item_id,interest_id)
)
select  p.page_id, i.item_id
from    (
    select p.page_id, interest_id, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY page_id) AS total_interests
    FROM    pages p
    ) p
LEFT JOIN items i
    ON  i.interest_id = p.interest_id
group by p.page_id, i.item_id, p.total_interests
HAVING COUNT(i.item_id) >= p.total_interests
```

The idea is to keep track of total page interests and then make sure it's no less than item counts (if we miss, LEFT JOIN value becomes null and COUNT ignores is).

Answer (score 0):

Using an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables, will make appear only interest_id in common between the two tables. To gather only <page_id, item_id> that have both the two pages, it's sufficient to enforcing `COUNT(DISTINCT i.interest_id) = 2` inside the `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT p.page_id, i.item_id
FROM       pages_interest p
INNER JOIN items_interest i
        ON p.interest_id = i.interest_id
GROUP BY p.page_id, i.item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.interest_id) = 2
```

If you want to generalize on the number of "*pages_interest*" items, you can do:

```
SELECT p.page_id, i.item_id
FROM       pages_interest p
INNER JOIN items_interest i
        ON p.interest_id = i.interest_id
GROUP BY p.page_id, i.item_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.interest_id) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT interest_id) FROM pages_interest)
```

Output:

| page_id | item_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/abEZIyRH).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure this quite works how I expected. It might be because I haven't explained very well. It could be that pages_interests has 1 to many of those rows for a specific page. There will not always be 2.

Comment: Have you seen the second solution?

Comment: Yes. When I use the updated data in my question, it doesn't return the expected output?

Comment: Can you share a fiddle, as the one at the bottom of my answer?